# Python 2.7 Escape with keyboard from reading serial data

Tags: python, python-2.7, keyboard, serial-port, escaping

I'm quite new in Python 2.7 and I need some help.
I want to write a script that will read data from a sensor using the serial port, and save all this data in a file, plus a time stamp. Sensor sends data periodically. I want the application to finish it's loop or simply receiving data, and close the file and the port, once it receives a predefined number of data, or when pressing a key in the keyboard. (For the moment any key will be enough).

The problem, is that it saves data in the correct way inside the file, but I was not able to escape and close the file by pressing a key. I guess that the shell might be blocked.. I don't see why it doesn´t work. Any help will be appreciated. I'm using Windows 7.

This is my code:

```
import serial
import io
from time import gmtime, strftime
import msvcrt

medidas= 10  
continuar=1
n_medidas=0

ser=serial.Serial(3,115200)
data_file=open ('data.txt','w')

fecha=strftime("(UTC) %a %d %b %Y %Hh:%Mm:%Ss",gmtime())
data_file.write('Datos enviados '+fecha+' por AP:\n')
data_file.write('Time_stamp' +'\t'+ 'EDx' +'\t'+ 'V(ADC)'+'\t'+'I(ADC)\n')

while continuar:
    tiempo=strftime("%Hh:%Mm:%Ss",gmtime())
    x=ser.readline()
    data=tiempo+'\t' +x 
    print (data)
    data_file.write(data)
    n_medidas += 1

    if msvcrt.kbhit():
        continuar=0

    if n_medidas == medidas :
        break

data_file.close()
ser.close()
```

Thanks.

Comment: you can always try ctrl+c in bash to kill a process even though i am not sure this is the proper way to achieve it.

Comment: Ctrl+c kills the process, but it doesn't close the file with the data received until that moment. The aim is to save all data read until the key is preesed in the file. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To do this properly, you should use `select` from the module `select`.  It's an operating system facility to "wait" for data coming from several streams (in your case that sensor and the keyboard).

```
import select, sys

with open('/path/to/my/sensor') as sensorFile, \
     open('/path/to/sensorDumpFile', 'w') as sensorDump:
  while True:
    r, w, e = select.select([ sys.stdin, sensorFile ], [], [])
    if sys.stdin in r:  # data coming from keyboard?
      break  # bail out
    if sensorFile in r:
      dataFromSensor = os.read(sensorFile.fileno(), 50)  # reads what's there, at most 50 bytes
      sensorDump.write(dataFromSensor)
```

In case you want to react on single key presses, you need to set the tty to an unbuffered mode first, but I don't think that's your topic right now.  (Say so if you are interested in that as well.)

Comment: Thanks. I forget to mention I'm using Windows 7. While reading the documentation of select, it seems this is more for Unix, if I'm understanding well.

Comment: No, `select` is not restricted to Unix, and if you are using files and stdin only, this should work.  There are differences concerning sockets, AFAIK, though.